# Curly brackets converted into hex code when used as link href

Tags: email, jsp, url-encoding

Curly brackets are converted into its hex code when present in a link href. I have an email function which sends a url (which has curly brackets in it). When clicked on the link in email, curly brackets are converted into its hex code (%7B and %7D) which results in failure of opening the web page.
I use jsp, javascript and html.

I get details from a form (including the link to be send) and send to a jsp page. The link is encoded using javascript encodeURIComponent and decoded in jsp using java.net.URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8"). This decodes the value perfectly but when it is written as href of link, only curly braces converted to hex code.

Its adobe scene7 image url which is something like

www.somedomain.com/PROD_NAME?wid=600&sharpen=1&color=235,198,59&obj=shirt/shirt_fabric/pocket&decal&sharp=0&src=is{sample/test3/ugc//9895846.tif?wid=150}&pos=0,1.2&res=30

It appears in mail as it is, but when clicked on that link it appears in browser as

www.somedomain.com/PROD_NAME?wid=600&sharpen=1&color=235,198,59&obj=shirt/shirt_fabric/pocket&decal&sharp=0&src=is%7Bsample/test3/ugc//9895846.tif?wid=150%7D&pos=0,1.2&res=30

and this causes failure on processing the url.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code and the relevant portion of the before/after URLs.

Comment: Why does it fail to decode? Does it work with other encoded characters?

Comment: You might rename your question to "How to decode [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) curly braces in jsp", if that is what you want.

Comment: It decodes perfectly, but when I click on the link, it gets encoded again

Answer (score 1):

If you have not come across a solution yet, you can replace the curly brackets with parentheses.

For example:

`www.somedomain.com/PROD_NAME?wid=600&sharpen=1&color=235,198,59&obj=shirt/shirt_fabric/pocket&decal&sharp=0&src=is{sample/test3/ugc//9895846.tif?wid=150}&pos=0,1.2&res=30`

to

`www.somedomain.com/PROD_NAME?wid=600&sharpen=1&color=235,198,59&obj=shirt/shirt_fabric/pocket&decal&sharp=0&src=is(sample/test3/ugc//9895846.tif?wid=150)&pos=0,1.2&res=30`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that won't work. As I mentioned, it is a scene7 image url, which will show an error as malformed url. So I send it as an attachment instead of sending url.

Comment: Compare: [Curly Brackets](http://s7d7.scene7.com/is/agm/S7Web/Photo_Card-2pg-2?&page=1&fmt=png&wid=648&cache=off&$Name=Scene7%20Guest&$Pg1_Line1=Happy%20Birthday&$Pg1_Line2=Many%20Happy%20Returns&$Text_Color=070707&$Background_color=c4e2ed&$Font=Cochin%20LT%20Std&$Photo=is{S7WebUGC2/ugc/1804769.tif}) to [Parentheses](http://s7d7.scene7.com/is/agm/S7Web/Photo_Card-2pg-2?&page=1&fmt=png&wid=648&cache=off&$Name=Scene7%20Guest&$Pg1_Line1=Happy%20Birthday&$Pg1_Line2=Many%20Happy%20Returns&$Text_Color=070707&$Background_color=c4e2ed&$Font=Cochin%20LT%20Std&$Photo=is(S7WebUGC2/ugc/1804769.tif))